# How do I stop Organizer from crashing Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos

Every time I open Organizer on Xcode, it crashes the entire application. Momentarily the Organizer window will pop up and then all Xcode windows will be wiped and the app will show as completely closed. It doesn't matter which project I open it for, and I've tried making sure everything has finished building/setting up before attempting to open it. I've also tried moving to Trash and reinstalling Xcode. Does anyone have any idea what would be causing this to happen and how to fix it? I have Xcode 14.3.1 installed on  M1 MacBook Pro with Ventura macOS 13.5.

Comment: Seems like [others](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/678986) have this happen to them as well although with seemingly earlier version of Xcode. Some users described trying a different version of Xcode. Have you tried the current Xcode-beta and seen the same crashing with it?

Comment: Updated to Xcode version 15 beta 6 and am experiencing the same issue when trying to open Organizer. I'm betting it's some sort of caching error so I've tried a couple methods for clearing various caches, but I'm not sure which would be related to the Organizer crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to eventually get it working by completely erasing my mac and all settings. Frustrating fix, but I'm just glad it worked.